# Prevent react router from pinging Django server

Tags: reactjs, django, url, react-router, router

so I have app in React with Router and Django on backend. I have Dashboard component, where I send request to Django for getting posts. But when I go on /dashboard, via Link or URL in browser, I get two requests on server:
GET /dashboard
GET /posts

Why I'm having this /dashboard request and how to stop react for pinging django with this request? Router look like this (two wrappers for giving store data and authenticate):

```
<Router history={history}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path={urls.get('home')}>
                                <Home/>
                            </Route>
                            <AuthProvider>
                                <DataProvider>
                                    <Route exact path={urls.get('dashboard')}>
                                        <Dashboard/>
                                    </Route>

...
```

### AuthProvider

```
function authenticate() {
    return API.refreshToken({'refresh': localStorage.getItem('refresh')}).then(response =>
    localStorage.setItem('access',response.data.access))
}

const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        authenticate().then(() => {
            setLogged(true)
            }
        ).catch(error => {
            setLogged(false);
        });
    }, []);


    return isLogged ? (<>{children}</>) : <p>Niezalogowany</p>;
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

### Data Provider

```
const DataProvider = inject("userStore", "postStore", "uiStore")(({userStore, postStore, children}) => {

    const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        API.getUser().then(response => {
            userStore.user = response.data;
            userStore.viewProfileId = userStore.user.id;
        }).then(() => API.getPosts().then(response => {
                postStore.posts = response.data
            })
        ).then(() => {
                if (userStore.user)
                    setFetched(true)
            }
        ).catch(error => {
            setFetched(false);
        });
    }, [userStore.user]);

    return fetched ? (<>{children}</>) : <p>Fetching data...</p>;
});

export default DataProvider;
```

### As for the requests:

```
getPosts: () => getAuth('/get_posts/'),
...
export function getAuth(path, requestHeaders) {
    return httpAuth.get(path, { headers: requestHeaders});
}
...
const httpAuth = axios.create({
    baseURL: APP_URL,
    timeout: 15000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`
    }
});
...
const APP_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';
```

Comment: Can you show the full Dashboard component?

Comment: Hi, its just normal functional component which in first useState makes an axios get request

Comment: You want us to debug your component that's making two get requests instead of one... Show us where those requests are being made and the surrounding component. You might be using hooks incorrectly, but we can't have any idea what's actually wrong unless we see that code...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by making the request in useState. An API call would typically live in useEffect and if you add an empty array as the dependency (second argument) then it will only run once when that component mounts.

Comment: *Yeah, I meant useEffect with empty array. So, every component in my route is wrapped in wrappers AuthProvider and DataProvider. I've edited question with wrappers and fetching info.

Comment: I think this might be normal if you are using server side rendering? If you go into the Network tab in dev tools and find that dashboard request, then click into `Preview`, what does it show?

Comment: After entering to dashboard page, or refreshing it, in network I have two dashboard/ requests. One is 200 OK, returning html page, and other one is red, 404 and it shows not found in Django url patterns. That's the point. I don't want this 404 request to be send to Django every time.